# How can a Nagios service depend fail when service #1 _and_ #2 goes down

Tags: nagios

I am currently configuring dependencies between Nagios services. Setting up one service depending on another is straight forward, but **is it possible to have one service failing when *all* master services are failing**?

My example as hand is a load balanser for failover. The load balancer will work correctly as long as any of its backends are functioning correctly.

Comment: Hang on, do you really mean "and" or "or"? If srv1 is up, but srv2 is down, should master be up or down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the documentation on [Monitoring server and host clusters](http://nagios.manubulon.com/traduction/docs14en/clusters.html), which describes I think exactly addresses your question.  Also see the [man page for the check_cluster plugin](http://nagiosplugins.org/man/check_cluster).  The `check_cluster` plugin can be configured to raise an alert based on the status of groups of other hosts or services.